# How to compute the mean value of the n first valid values of a rolling window in xarray/dask without huge loss of performance?

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I am working on an algorithm that detects changes in time-series of gridded data. The data is loaded as huge Dask xarrays on an HPC cluster, and it usually varies between 0 and 1, but there are random NaN values distributed within it.

At some point, my algorithm should compute the mean of the next n values over the t-axis, taking into account *only the valid (non-NaN) values* for every (x, y, t) position. This is tricky because the `.rolling` method takes all values, including the non-valid, to compute the average.

I have tried some approaches to solve this problem:

1. Using `result = data.rolling(t=n).mean()` leads to the computation of many mean values with less than n valid values, which I should avoid.
2. Using `result = data.rolling(t=n*2,min_periods=n).mean()` leads to the computation of many mean values with *more* than n valid values, which I should avoid too.
3. Finally, I wrote a custom function like this:

   ```
   def mean_exact_n(array):
       return np.mean(array[np.isfinite(array)][:n])

   def mean_exact_n_along_axis(array, axis):
       return np.apply_along_axis(mean_exact_n, axis, array)

   change_index = db.rolling(t=n*2, min_periods=n).reduce(mean_exact_n_along_axis)
   ```

   This solution gives me the exact result, but it drastically reduces the performance of the algorithm, making it unusable from an operational point of view.

I have included a toy example below that exactly reproduces the problem that I am facing.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.array as da
from datetime import datetime

# Create Dask client
client = Client()

# Create toy data
x = y = t = 200
data = da.from_array(np.random.rand(x, y, t))
db = xr.DataArray(
    data,
    [
        ("x", pd.Series(range(x))),
        ("y", pd.Series(range(y))),
        ("t", pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=t)),
    ],
).chunk({"x": 50, "y": 50, "t": 20})

# place some NaN
db = db.where(db < 0.8)

# Define reduction functions
n = 3


def mean_exact_n(array):
    return np.mean(array[np.isfinite(array)][:n])


def mean_exact_n_along_axis(array, axis):
    return np.apply_along_axis(mean_exact_n, axis, array)


# Compute the exact result
t = datetime.now()
c = (
    db.rolling(t=n * 2, center=False, min_periods=n)
    .reduce(mean_exact_n_along_axis)
    .compute()
)
print(datetime.now() - t)  # 0:00:34.105421

# Compute the approximate result
t = datetime.now()
c2 = (
    db.rolling(t=n * 2, center=False, min_periods=n)
    .mean(skipna=True)
    .compute()
)
print(datetime.now() - t)  # 0:00:05.912579
```

The exact solution is five times slower than the approximate one. I am struggling to understand the problem behind this. Looking at the Dask dashboard, I noticed that there is an issue with parallelization because only a few tasks are being executed at the same time.

As I am not an Xarray/Dask/Computer Science expert, any advice on this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer myself. The solution I've found is based in Numba runtime compiling:

```
import numba
@numba.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy",cache=True)
def mean_exact_n(array: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return np.mean(array[np.isfinite(array)][:n])


def mean_exact_n_along_axis_numba(array, axis):
    return np.apply_along_axis(mean_exact_n, axis, array)
```

By applying this, I've achieved x7 speed gain on my operational workflow. Now is almost as fast as the original 'non-exact' function.